# How to determine the number of charecter will fit to screen in Qt

Tags: qt, fonts, qt4, screen, nokia

How do I determine the number of characters in a particular font will fit to the screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [QFontMetrics](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qfontmetrics.html). Using this, you can determine, among other things, the width of a particular string:

```
QFontMetrics metrics(myFont);
int width = metrics.width(myString);
```

Is this what you want?

**Note:** It is not possible to find the number of characters of a particular font that will fit on the screen since not all fonts are monospace. So the number of characters will depend on the actual characters.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `QFontMetrics::elidedText` passing available space (remember to reduce it with margins/paddings. Then call length on result string